# Overloading stream << operator for pointer / shared pointer and other types

Tags: c++, stream, operator-overloading

Is it possible to overload the << operator for a custom class in a way that all of following will work:

```
CustomClass customClass;
std::shared_ptr<CustomClass> sharedPointer(customClass);

os << customClass;
os << sharedPointer;
```

Or that at least following works:

```
os << sharedPointer.get();
```

By default, using the common technique to overload the `operator`, only following 2 options will work:

```
os << customClass;
os << *sharedPointer.get();
```

**Edit**

"working" here means, that in all cases the custom classes `<<` operator overload is executed and that I get the result of `os << customClass` in all cases instead of pointer addresses in the case of the pointer classes

**Example**

Code:

```
os << customClass;
os << sharedPointer;
os << sharedPointer.get();
os << *sharedPointer.get();
```

Output:

```
Custom class text
00000244125655C0
00000244125655C0
Custom class text
```

Desired:

At second or third output should be "Custom class text" as well

Comment: What would you expect as output? The address?

Comment: No, this is what I get. I want that the wrapped custom classes `<<` operator is called

Comment: fixed the terminology errors

Comment: @prom85 It should be possible to do the overload. What specifically did you try and how did it fail?

Comment: You can't overload any operators for primitive types. You forgot one option, though: `os << *sharedPointer;`, which is what people normally use.

Comment: You're right, was not aware that I can dereference the shared pointer without calling get

Comment: I'm just testing this again - I could swear I tried this already, but yeah, this is what I was asking for

Comment: IMO, having `s << p` output `*p` for a pointer `p` is a bad idea which would make code much harder to reason about. Streaming a pointer, I expect a pointer in the steam. If I wanted to stream the object, I would dereference the pointer. Such an overload as you propose would never pass code review with me.

Comment: @Angew Good and valid point. Not everything possible should be done, won't pass a code review from my side as well.

Comment: Will take the concerns into account and use dereferencing instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> that in all cases the custom classes << operator overload is executed and that I get the result of os << customClass in all cases instead of pointer addresses in the case of the pointer classes

Here's how I would do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class MyClass {
    std::string s;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyClass& c) {
        os << c.s;
        return os;
    }

public:
    MyClass(const std::string& s_) : s(s_) {}
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::shared_ptr<T>& pc) {
    os << pc.get() << " " << *pc;
    return os;
}    


int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> pc = std::make_shared<MyClass>("Hello");
    std::cout << pc << std::endl;
}
```

Output

```
0x20f5c30 Hello
```

See a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ea44eecefc0d060).

Comment: [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53aa2efcfff48ae7) version is ok and works even when used with namespaces because [Argument Dependent Lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) also includes the template arguments (here `T = MyClass`) in where it looks for applicable functions. But where would you suggest putting this generic `operator<<` for `shared_ptr`?